# Fill the Image Sequence Ep. 1

Tags: pattern, visual

Well, I just figure out another puzzle type, let find out whether it could be the good series or not :P

This puzzle will provide several images, and **these images compose a sequence with one or more properties**. Please try to identify what the properties contained by this sequence, **making images get *grouped* and *ordered*, and answer the missing one.**

**The answer should include an image, and a few reasons to illustrate why you pick the image.** Note that the answer might not be unique, any image which meets the properties is correct(The green check may give to the first correct answer).

---

**Question:**

[image]$\to$
[image]$\to$
[image]$\to$
**$(?)$**$\to$
[image]$\to$
[image]

Comment: I'm going to give a feedback for this series. Imho, this will be a good and interesting series; but, we should be more careful to setup the puzzle. In particular for this puzzle, the answers are based on.. "popularity".. which is kinda subjective. Like number sequence, they shouldn't invite speculative answer. More specific: ROT13(Lrf, vg'f fbegrq ol gur fvmr bs gur onyy. Ubjrire, gurer ner znal bgure fcbegf jvgu onyy'f fvmr orgjrra pevpxrg naq fbppre.) Still, it's a nice concept and I'm looking forward for the next puzzles :)

Comment: @athin Yes I agree that, rot13(ohg V pbhyqa'g qb rkunhfgvba gb rafher gung gurer vf bayl bar nafjre gb svg gur frdhrapr, sbe guvf chmmyr. Znlor V pbhyq znxr nabgure chmmyr sebz n svavgr vzntr frg znl zrrg lbhe fhttrfgvba.) Anyway, this is another trial for new type puzzles, cheers :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think they are:

> The corners of courts/fields of the 6 most popular sports in the world.
>
>   1. Ping Pong table
>   2. Tennis court
>   3. Cricket field
>   4. (Answer) Volleyball court 
>
>   [image] 
>
> 5. Soccer field
> 6. Basketball court
>
>   The order is still unknown because these are not in the order of most popular to least popular. It might have to do with counties hat won world titles this year or something like that.
>
>   They are also alternating **field, court, field, court** even when you put in volleyball court.
>
>  As @Weather Vane mentioned, the courts could be organized by the size of ball from smallest to largest.

Comment: You may compare something to decide the order, yet the "field, court, field, court" finding is good that I didn't notice that :D

Comment: rot13(Ibyyrlonyy nyfb svgf vs lbh pbafvqre gung gurl ner beqrerq ol gur fvmr bs gur onyy.)

Comment: rot13(Npghnyyl V'z jebat. Gur fvmr bs gur graavf onyy vf fznyyre guna gur pevpxrg onyy. Fbeel sbe gung.)

Comment: @Pretzel in that case it's the **right** order;) There is a list here at partial rot13(https://onyyf.pbz/ehyrf/juvpu-onyy-vf-ovttre.html). Rot13(Ohg #1 gura pna'g or evtug. Naljnl vg ybbxf zber yvxr n gnoyr graavf gnoyr guna n svryq be cvgpu, rkprcg hfhnyyl gur yvarf ner evtug ng gur rqtr).

Comment: Maybe the green mark is about to be given soon :D

Comment: Yes, the first pic is rot13(ovwgzoziidn) :P

Comment: @Conifers Your spoiler is rot5, not rot13